# How to switch language on pages containing charts created using Forena?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, forena

I have created a chart using [Forena Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena). I have created a menu with this chart as one of the links.

I have also installed the [Language Switcher Dropdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) module for choosing between 3 languages. When I choose between any of the languages, the page will get refreshed and I will be able to see the transalated version.

But this is not happening when I am in the chart page. When I choose other language page is not even getting refreshed also language is not getting changed. When I go to other pages and try the same, everything is working as expected.

[image]

**Note**: When I go to the chart page I can see this error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

which is coming from the `datatables.js file` inside the forena report.

Comment: maybe setting the output type of the language switcher block to *Simple HTML select* will make it work again. if this not works, check also **the other options**, maybe the conflict dissolves ;)

Comment: there is probably a JS error/conflict. if so, can you post it ?

Comment: That is the option I have chosen. It is not working.

Comment: well, this still uses JS ... so - is there an error in your javascript console ? have you tried the other options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the "**uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function**" you mentioned, it sounds to me that what your language problem is actually not a language problem, but some installation issue related to what's required to [Enable Data Tables](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.setup#datatables) support. I'd recommend you to first try to resolve that error (as explained in the documentation in the mink I mentioned before, which you can also find in your own site located at `/reports/help.setup#datatables`.

You may also want to look at my answer to the question about "[How to translate the title, axis labels and legend of a chart?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177485/how-to-translate-the-title-axis-labels-and-legend-of-a-chart/177557#177557)" for the typical steps required to correctly translate a chart create with Forena (just to make sure such translation exist for each of your languages, and that the URL for each translation of the report is correct, and does exist).

If neither of this helps to sort out what's happening, then please further enhance your question by including your report/chart specifications (= what's called the "frx"-source in Forena). After doing so, I'd be happy to try to further enhance my answer also.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Forena Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).

Comment: Yes that should be possible. Have a look at my answer at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176901/how-to-show-the-values-on-the-bars-of-a-stacked-bar-graph-in-3d/176904#176904 (the option 2 part of it). If that doesn't help, please create a new question with some more details about what exactly you want to further refine, OK?